# Search for same data in two different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

hey  this is my database

```
 users table                               pages table

|user_firstname|                           |page_firstname |
-----------------------------              --------------------------------
|  john    |                               |  matt    | 
|  james   |                               |  quentin | 
|  harry   |                               |  roland  |   
|  oliver  |                               |  thomas  |
```

And this is my query for a search application

```
SELECT user_id,   
       user_firstname, 
       user_lastname,
       user_profile_picture 
FROM users 
WHERE user_firstname LIKE :user_firstname
OR user_lastname LIKE :user_lastname
```

It works for users table. However I want to search from pages column too. For example when I press the letter M it founds jaMes, but I want Matt and thoMas as well. The thing is if I type Q it should only find the Quentin from the pages and if I type J it should only from the users.
how do I include the pages table in this query?

UPDATE I tried this query

```
SELECT user_id, 
       user_firstname, 
       user_lastname, 
       user_profile_picture 
FROM users 
WHERE user_firstname LIKE :user_firstname 
OR user_lastname LIKE :user_lastname 
UNION ALL SELECT page_id, 
                 page_firstname,  
                 page_lastname,  
                 page_profile_picture 
FROM pages 
WHERE page_firstname LIKE :page_firstname 
OR page_lastname LIKE :page_lastname
```

and my result was like this:

```
array (size=4)
  'user_id' => int 5
  'user_firstname' => string 'Roland' (length=3)
  'user_lastname' => string 'lastname' (length=7)
  'user_profile_picture' => string '5_1399841223_536fe1c70ea2b_user_profile.jpg' (length=43)
```

even if the roland was in the PAGES table i am getting the result like it is in users table. i would like to separate them from each other

Comment: either a `UNION` or (more likely) just do two queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this :

```
SELECT user_id,
 user_firstname,
 user_lastname,
 user_profile_picture, 'users' as 'type'
FROM users 
WHERE user_firstname LIKE :user_firstname
OR user_lastname LIKE :user_lastname 
UNION ALL SELECT page_id, 
 page_firstname, 
 page_lastname, 
 page_profile_picture ,'pages' as 'type'
FROM pages 
WHERE page_firstname LIKE :page_firstname 
OR page_lastname LIKE :page_lastname
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you're trying to accomplish - if you want to basically treat them like the same table then something like this would work

```
SELECT user_id,   
       user_firstname, 
       user_lastname,
       user_profile_picture 
FROM users 
WHERE user_firstname LIKE :user_firstname
OR user_lastname LIKE :user_lastname
UNION ALL
SELECT user_id,   
       user_firstname, 
       user_lastname,
       user_profile_picture 
FROM pages
WHERE user_firstname LIKE :user_firstname
OR user_lastname LIKE :user_lastname
```

Comment: this is my actual query: SELECT user_id, user_firstname, user_lastname, user_profile_picture FROM users WHERE user_firstname LIKE :user_firstname OR user_lastname LIKE :user_lastname UNION ALL SELECT page_id,  page_firstname,  page_lastname,  page_profile_picture FROM pages WHERE page_firstname LIKE :page_firstname OR page_lastname LIKE :page_lastname BUT the thing is i am getting all the data as user_id, user_firstname etc. i want to know if it is from pages table or users table how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might work, untested. Except for an experiment in http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp.

```
SELECT user_id as user_id,   
           user_firstname as firstname, 
           user_lastname as lastname,
           user_profile_picture as profile_picture 
   FROM users 
   WHERE user_firstname LIKE :user_firstname
     OR user_lastname LIKE :user_lastname
   union
   SELECT pages_id as user_id,   
       pages_firstname as firstname, 
       pages_lastname as lastname,
       pages_profile_picture as profile_picture 
    FROM pages 
    WHERE pages_firstname LIKE :user_firstname
    OR pages_lastname LIKE :user_lastname
```